# Amplifying user movement in game

Tags: c#, math, unity-game-engine

I'm making a game where the user would move an object using the leap motion. Using just the motion of the user doesn't have enough effect, so I'd like to amplify it.

What I've tried:
Saving the starting position of the object I want to move, and detecting the change from that point and multiplying it by two.
Also tried calculating it to the power of 10, but that just went to infinity very fast.

So that's all failed, I still feel this shouldn't be this hard, anything I'm missing?

EDIT: My current code, which is doing nothing at all.

```
        (WaterBallInst as GameObject).transform.position = new Vector3(
            (WaterBallInst as GameObject).transform.position.x + (gameObject.transform.position.x - WaterBallStartPos.x),
            (WaterBallInst as GameObject).transform.position.y + (gameObject.transform.position.y - WaterBallStartPos.y),
            (WaterBallInst as GameObject).transform.position.z + (gameObject.transform.position.z - WaterBallStartPos.z));
```

Here gameObject is the user movement and WaterBallInst is what I'm trying to move

Comment: like someone is really supposed to know what you are doing without seeing the code.. so If you read this question I would ask how you would answer this one..

Comment: *"Also tried calculating it to the power of 10, but that just went to infinity very fast"* Sounds like you were missing some limiting code, I'm guessing you were multiplying every frame? Try doing it based on time, and then limit it to some maximum value.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, Added the code, I had a feeling I needed to limit it, but I can't think of a way how. At the rate it's going now, I can't even see it going away, it's just to infinity within a second. I am doing this every frame. How would I do it based on time?

Comment: I'm not real up on unity, but its something like speed += (rate * diffInTime/totalTimeToRate).